# [PHP and forms]: Submit button generates correct link only the second time

Tags: php, html, forms

I am struggling with PHP and a form.

```
</div><div class="page-header">
<h2><?= t('Ticker settings for project "%s"', $project['name']) ?></h2>
</div>
<div>
    <form id= "ticker" method="post" action="<?= $this->url-
>href('TickerController', 'set_ticker', array('project_id' => 
$project['id'], 'ticker_text' => $_POST['textbox_ticker_text'])) ?
>&plugin=Ticker">

    <?= t('Ticker text:') ?><br>

    <input type="text" id="textbox" accept-charset="UTF-8" 
name="textbox_ticker_text" value="<?php echo $project['ticker_text'];?>">
    <?= $this->modal->submitButtons();?>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ok here's the problem:
The first time I press the submit button - a wrong link is being generated. It does not contain the textbox "textbox_ticker_text". After I press the Submit button again, the text is being included into the link. Still the second time I press the button the text from the first time will be given to the "TickerController" and written to the database.

I cant figure out what causes this strange behaviour.
Could anyone give me a hint?

PS:
Just to make things clear:

a) I type in "666" and press Submit -> "" is written into the DB.

b) I type in "777" and press Submit -> "666" is being written into the DB and the hyperlink contains "666" and not "777".

It seems like the page is always a step behind.

Comment: Your form action makes no sense. You are using the post method but then sending in a POST parameter to the action. This is only set after form is sent so no wonder it is one step behind. Move it as an input parameter on the form and check for POST vars in your controller instead

Comment: Ok, well that already helped me!

Comment: I have posted this an answer in this case so we can comment further together or you can accept the answer so it wont show up in the unanswered feed any more.

Comment: After the first click on the submit button the text was written into the database. I only have one problem left:
When I update the text, after the submit, the correct variable is the new ticker-text, but the textbox still shows the old text. Can I reload the textbox somehow to show immediately the change I made?

Comment: Change it to `$_POST['textbox_ticket_text']` ?

Comment: I got it! Thank you so much - your simple hint just made me think different and I was able to solve my problem -  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you out :-) Have a great day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form `action` makes no sense. You are using the `post` `method` but then sending in a `POST` parameter to the `action`. This is only set after the form is sent so that is why it is one step behind.

You now have two options.

1. Move the passed `POST` field as an input parameter on the form and check for `POST` vars in your controller instead.
2. Change the `method` to `get` and do away with the query string in the action parameter (this will assume no sensitive data is getting passed through) and create hidden fields for what you want to pass through.